# Every acummulation point is a estacionary point when using steepest descent method

Tags: analysis, statistics, optimization

Firstly in order to correctly formulate my question I will define the concepts required.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function which we want to minimize

A gradient method is one of the form $x^{k+1}=x^k+\alpha^kd^k$ where $d^k$ is the chosen direction.

We say that the sucession $\alpha^k$ is chosen by minimization rule if
$\alpha^k= min_{\alpha\in\mathbb{R}}f(x^k+\alpha d^k)$

We say that the sucession $d^k$ is of gradient form if for every subsuccesion that converges to a non estacionary point then:

1. $d^k$ is bounded for every $k\in K$
2. $limsup_{k\in K} \nabla f(x^k)'d^k<0$

Then I would like to prove a proposal that states that if $x^k$ is a sucession generated by the gradient method, that is, $x^{k+1}=x^k+\alpha^kd^k$, with $d^k$ of gradient form and $\alpha^k$ of minimization rule then every acummulation point is an estacionary point ($\nabla f(\bar{x})=0$)

I have been working for proving it but still I am missing one point to prove in my approach.

If we suppose that $\alpha^k \rightarrow 0$ when $k \rightarrow \infty$ then I can proceed as follows.

By reduction to absurd let's suppose that $\bar{x}$ is a accumulation point for $x^k$ but non estacionary.

We can do the first order Taylor development for $f$

$$f(x^k+\alpha^kd^k)=f(x^k)+\alpha^k \nabla f(x^k)'d^k+o(\alpha^{2k})$$
$$\frac{f(x^k+\alpha^kd^k)-f(x^k)}{\alpha^k}= \nabla f(x^k)'d^k+\frac{o(\alpha^{2k})}{\alpha^k}$$

Usin the MVT

(1) $$\nabla f(x^k+\tilde{\alpha}^kd^k)d^k=\nabla f(x^k)'d^k+\frac{o(\alpha^2k)}{\alpha^k}$$

where $\tilde{\alpha}^k\in[0,\alpha^k]$

Now as $\alpha$ is chosen by minimization rule we deduce that

$\nabla f(x^k+\alpha^kd^k)'d^k=0$

Then tending $k \rightarrow \infty$ we get from (1) to

$$0=\nabla f(\bar{x})'\bar{d}^k 0 \leq limsup_{k\in K} \nabla f(x^k)'d^k<0$$

And that's the contradiction. Therefore $\bar{x}$ is indeed estacionary.

Nervertheless I don't find a way of proving that $\alpha^k$ tends to 0 and I need that to justify that $\tilde\alpha^k$ tends to 0

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: What is $K$? How you you know that $\alpha^k$ exists?

Comment: The set $K$ I understand that it needs to be a subset of natural numbers for the subsuccesion selected as for the second question taking into account that $f(x^{k+1})=f(x^k)+\alpha^k \nabla f(x^k)'d^k+o(\alpha^{k})$ then for obtaining $f(x^{k+1})\leq f(x^k)$ then $\alpha$ needs to be small enough. I think that may justify its existence

Comment: Well, we also take $d^k$ such that $\nabla f(x^k)d^k<0$